# An inequality for complex number $|a+b|^p \sim |a|^p+|b|^p$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I know that for any nonnegative numbers $a,b$ and $1\leq p<\infty$ then $a^p+b^p\leq (a+b)^p\leq 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$.

Now we need to find the similar inequalities for complex numbers. My question is if these exist a similar version for $a,b$ are complex numbers. Namely,  do there exist constants $C_p,c_p>0$ so that $c_p(|a|^p+|b|^p)\leq |a+b|^p\leq C_p(|a|^p+|b|^p)$ hold for all complex $a,b$ ?.

How could we find $c_p,C_p$ if this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = |a|, B = |b|$. Then, $A$ and $B$ are non-negative real numbers and you know from your original inequality that

$$2^{p-1} (|a|^p + |b|^p) = 2^{p-1}(A^p +B^p) \ge (A+B)^p = (|a|+|b|)^p \ge |a+b|^p$$

where the last inequality is obtained via the triangle inequality in the complex plane. Hence, $C_p = 2^{p-1}$ works here and this is a minimum since if we select $a=b$ we have 
$$ |a+b|^p  = 2^p |a|^p = 2^{p-1}(|a|^p + |b|^p)$$

Less interesting perhaps is the fact that $c_p = 0$.

Take, for example $a=i, b=-i$, then $|a|^p + |b|^p = 2$ but $|a+b|^p = 0$ so, even in this simple case there is no positive $c_p$ to make the inequality work.